# NDK 'make' not found

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

I have 'imported existing android code' into adt as a project. Now it is throwing the error Program "make" no found in path.

I have read other topics about point eclispe to cygwin or something, but I though the latest build of the NDK does not need anything else installed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have cygwin installed, maybe make isn't there ? you need to install "make" from cygwin installer. If make is already installed, you should try adding cygwin's path to your environment.

On another hand, cygwin isn't required at all int the latest NDK releases. You can simply remove it if you don't need it for anything particular, and the ndk will use its own toolchain.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I am using the latest NDK build, so maybe I should just remove cygwin, if this is what you are suggesting. How do I go about doing that?

Comment: Yes that should solve your issue. You just need to remove the cygwin folder, the `CYGWIN` env variable, and cygwin path from your `PATH` environment variable.